# Getting a long-lived User Access Token for Instagram Graph API

Tags: facebook, instagram, instagram-api

We are building a mobile app on behalf of a corporation and the API needs to be able to return the corporation's Instagram feed.  We have found that implementing what should be a simple requirement incredibly difficult.

We need to retrieve the following Instagram post data from the corporation's feed:

- image url
- caption
- url to post
- timestamp

With this in mind we identified that we need to use the [Instagram Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/) which means there are strict requirements around permissions.

**Note:** We are open to using any method that returns us the required data.

Using the Instagram Graph API we need to use the following endpoints:

- [Media](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/) (to get a list of the latest IG Media objects for a user)
- [IG Media](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media) to get detail about each media object

This works fine but the problem lies with getting a [long-lived User Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/long-lived-access-tokens/). To get this kind of token we need the `instagram_graph_user_media` permission. The [Long-Lived Access Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/long-lived-access-tokens/) documentation says:

> Long-lived tokens are valid for 60 days and can be refreshed as long as they are at least 24 hours old but have not expired, ***and the app user has granted your app*** the `instagram_graph_user_profile` permission.

How can the app user (the corporation) grant the app the permission? As I mentioned this is for an app on behalf of a corporation.

Any help here would be really appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: You ask for permissions during login. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/getting-access-tokens-and-permissions

Comment: There is no login. This is an app for a client to show their own Instagram feed...

Comment: There has to be a login _somewhere_, user access tokens don’t magically appear out of thin air.

Comment: Ok thanks. Do you know of another way to get the data we want without using a User Access Token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you go through the App review process in Facebook? Whenever there are user permissions involved, you need to go through the App review process for your app. Even though you don't use user permissions, some user permissions are pre-requisites for some business permissions.

Read the article here for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-review

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if this will be of any help, but battling exactly the same thing today came across this and it made for some intresting reading https://solrevdev.com/2020/05/28/instagram-basic-display-api.html

Comment: Can you share how you ended up getting a long-lived access token in your case?

Comment: I've been trying to follow this https://youtu.be/X4ueUbNFQtw but seems more app oriented. I am.lookomg to pull the public posts so the user isn't logged in. I do not need to know anything about the user.